# Jacoco: Can't add different class with same name

Tags: azure-devops, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin, jacoco-plugin

I realize there are several similar issues out there, but none of the solutions work for me. I'm building a Spring Boot Java service in an Azure pipeline.

```
 - task: Maven@3
    displayName: 'Build'
    inputs:
      mavenPomFile: 'pom.xml'
      goals: 'clean org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:report package'
      publishJUnitResults: true
      codeCoverageToolOption: jacoco
      testResultsFiles: '**/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
```

I'm getting the following error as I run the build

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.8:run (default) on project VstsReport: An Ant BuildException has occured: Error while creating report
[ERROR] around Ant part ...<report>... @ 8:11 in /home/vsts/work/1/s/myApp/target/antrun/build-main.xml: Error while analyzing apiservice/target/apiservice-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar@BOOT-INF/lib/log4j-api-2.13.3.jar@org/apache/logging/log4j/util/ProcessIdUtil.class. Can't add different class with same name: org/apache/logging/log4j/util/ProcessIdUtil
```

I'm attempting to Exclude, but no matter what I put in the Exclude tag, nothing is working. The exclude below do not work. I have tried all permutations I can think of. Even this:

```
<exclude>**/*.*</exclude>
```

does absolutely nothing. I must be doing something else wrong.

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>../apiservice-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>                    
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>prepare-agent</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>report</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>                    
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

The plugin seems to acknowledge the exclude statements as they are represented in the log output below.

> ```
> [INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.4:prepare-agent (default-prepare-agent-vsts) @ apiservice ---
> [INFO] argLine set to -javaagent:/home/vsts/.m2/repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.8.4/org.jacoco.agent-0.8.4-runtime.jar=destfile=/home/vsts/work/1/s/rulesengine/CCReport43F6D5EF/jacoco.exec,includes=**/*,excludes=../apiservice-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
> [INFO] 
> [INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.4:prepare-agent (prepare-agent) @ apiservice ---
> [INFO] argLine set to -javaagent:/home/vsts/.m2/repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.8.4/org.jacoco.agent-0.8.4-runtime.jar=destfile=/home/vsts/work/1/s/rulesengine/CCReport43F6D5EF/jacoco.exec,excludes=../apiservice-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
> ```

**UPDATE**:
Removing

```
codeCoverageToolOption: jacoco
```

from the Maven@3 task resolved all the problems. I don't know the purpose of that setting or why it completely overrides any setting in the pom.xml. I'm leaving this post here in case someone finds it useful.

Comment: The path set in the `exclude` element is relative to the directory `target/classes/`. But the errror message shows  the conflict class came from the `log4j-api-2.13.3.jar` in `apiservice-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` which resided in `target` folder instead of `target/classes/`. Could you have a try setting the exclude path to `<exclude>../apiservice-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar</exclude>`

Comment: @LeviLu-MSFT, I updated per your recommendation but still getting the same error. I included the log output above where you can see it looks like the exclude is setup correctly. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This had nothing to do with jacoco or pom.xml configuration. Removing codeCoverageToolOption: jacoco from the Maven@3 task made everything function as it should. I have no idea what that option does but I wasted a ton of time on it. I'll leave this post here as is in case someone finds it useful

Comment: That's great you fixed it. You can convert above comment to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This had nothing to do with plugin settings, jacoco or exclude paths. Turns out that removing this from the Maven@3 task fixed the issue.

```
codeCoverageToolOption: jacoco
```

I don't know the purpose of that setting or why it completely seem to override the pom.xml. I spent way too much time on this, but hopefully this will help someone else.